# LARAVEL: POST and GET routes with same name scrambling link_to_route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, named-routing

I got these routes:

```
    Route::get('prefix/list/{page?}/{size?}', ['as' => 'prefix.list', 'uses' => 'MyController@getList']);
    Route::post('prefix/list', ['as' => 'prefix.list', 'uses' => 'MyController@postList']);
```

When I call `link_to_route()` like so:

```
{{ link_to_route('prefix.list', $page, ['page' => $page, 'size' => $size]) }}
```

It creates this link:

> http://my.site/prefix/list?page=5&size=12

But when I remove the post route, it renders **correctly** this:

> http://my.site/prefix/list/5/12

I don't want to change the name of the routes because my system depends on them being the same. How can I solve this?

Comment: You could try just changing the order of the routes in your routes file, so that the get one comes last and overrides the post for the purposes of link_to_route(). Not 100 % sure it'll work, though.

Comment: @JoelHinz It worked! Post an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try just changing the order of the routes in your routes file, so that the get one comes last and overrides the post for the purposes of `link_to_route()`.